# Как подключить SSL Сертификат в Openserver

Tags: ssl, openserver, openssl

Привет всем, 
поделитесь опытом как подключить сертификат в Openserver, 
**Chrome** ругается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Mozilla Firefox** разрешил использовать(вернее сделал исключение) сертификат  по умолчанию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить подкиньте идею

Comment: Добавить сертификат удостоверяющего центра в доверенные.

Comment: Смотрите мой ответ [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/772737/%D0%A3%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-ssl-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-openserver)