# Установка ssl сертификата на OpenServer

Tags: ssl, https, openserver

Привет народ! 
Что-то я так и не нашёл как в Open Server можно подключить и настроить локальный ssl сертификат. Мануал почитал, там про это вообще не слово не встретил.

По этому вопрос, как установить и настроить ssl сертификат на Open Servere, что бы локальный адрес сайта был не http://localsite.ru, а http**s**://localsite.ru

Answer (score 2):

[Источник](https://ospanel.io/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=3574)
Скрипт для генерации сертификата (сохранить как `.bat` и выполнить с правами администратора):

```
@echo OFF
setlocal
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\openserver\modules\http\Apache-2.4\conf\openssl.cnf //заменить по необходимости
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\openserver\modules\http\Apache-2.4\bin //заменить по необходимости
set dname=mydomain //заменить по необходимости
set days=730
set key_bits=2048
set root_certs_path=C:\openserver\userdata\config\cert_files //заменить по необходимости

echo [trust_cert] > %dname%.cnf
echo subjectAltName=@alt_names >> %dname%.cnf
echo keyUsage=digitalSignature,keyEncipherment,dataEncipherment >> %dname%.cnf
echo extendedKeyUsage=serverAuth,clientAuth >> %dname%.cnf
echo [alt_names] >> %dname%.cnf
echo DNS.1 = %dname% >> %dname%.cnf
echo DNS.2 = %dname%.ospanel.io >> %dname%.cnf

openssl genrsa -out %dname%.key %key_bits%
openssl req -sha256 -new -utf8 -key %dname%.key -out %dname%.csr -subj /emailAddress="info\@ospanel\.io"/C=RU/stateOrProvinceName="Russian Federation"/L=Moscow/O="Open Server Panel"/OU=Software/CN=%dname% //заменить по необходимости
rem Для создания сертификата, подписанного доверенным сертификатом
openssl x509 -sha256 -req -days %days% -in %dname%.csr -extfile %dname%.cnf -extensions trust_cert -CA %root_certs_path%\rootCA.crt -CAkey %root_certs_path%\rootCA.key -out %dname%.crt
del %dname%.csr
del %dname%.cnf
pause
```

Копируете ключ и сертификат в `userdata\config\cert_files`.
Проверить правильность пути к сертификатам и ключам в соответственных конфигах apache (версии, которую вы используете, в вышеприведенном примере это 2.4) в строках, наподобие

```
ssl_certificate               "C:/openserver/userdata/config/cert_files/mydomain.crt";
ssl_certificate_key           "C:/openserver/userdata/config/cert_files/mydomain.key";
```

Перезапускаете openserver

Comment: Я пробовал так сделать. Но к сожалению не заработало. Пришлось переустановить OS. Скорее всего, что-то сделал не правильно

Comment: @СергейПризма в последней версии (5.2.2) все работает. Проверяйте правильности всех путей

Answer (score 0):

Всё очень просто. 
Дописываем к любому домену https, подтверждаем переход и всё, сайт работает на https.

Comment: И браузер выдаёт Вам что он не доверяет этому сайту

Comment: Не работает данный способ. Выдает ошибку

Comment: Он ругается, так как не может проверить поддельность сертификата. Достаточно просто **проигнорировать предупреждение браузера** и пользоваться сайтом по http**s**